# GetPixel(); X, Y is wrong

Tags: c

Soooo,

I have been trying to make a piano tiles bot but i just cant seem to get it to work.
It will click the correct location but the color detection is way of.
I'm using GetPixel but none of the things i could find seem to give me the correct values.
I know that the X,Y is wrong and i think it has to do with the resolution or scaling.
My current code is:

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void DisplayData(COLORREF color, POINT p)
{
    printf("{%i, %i, %i} {%i, %i}\n", GetRValue(color), GetGValue(color), GetBValue(color), p.x, p.y);
}

int main()
{
    POINT p;
    HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);

    while (1)
    {
        Sleep(400);

        GetCursorPos(&p);

        COLORREF color = GetPixel(dc, p.x, p.y);

        DisplayData(color, p);
    }

    ReleaseDC(NULL, dc);

    return 0;
}
```

My bottom x,y are {1535, 863}.
Is there a quick way to handle scaling?
Or is there another problem?

Comment: what's wrong with the colour detection?

Comment: Try adding `SetProcessDPIAware();` to the code. See: [Setting the default DPI awareness for a process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process).

Comment: @Johnny Mopp I cant seem to get it to work but i did manage to fix it. I multiply by my monitor scaling.